# Youtrack - unable to change to some statuses after linking a project to a board

Tags: youtrack

I get this error when I move the issue from In Progress to Done.

`Workflow jetbrains-youtrack-scrum reports error: Cannot find State [Done]
Contact project admin admin`

This was fine before, but has started behaving differently ever since the issue was also added to two boards.

Both the boards have "Done" as a valid status. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This workflow may fail with such an error if it is not possible to set 'Done' state to a parent issue.
Thus, most probably, this particular issue is a subtask of some other issue from another project, which doesn't have a 'Done' state in its 'State' field values set.